# Migrating from Bitbucket to Github and using Git Flow

Tags: github, gitflow, bitbucket

In our team we have up to 50 repos, of which about 15 are worked with regularly. The others are rarely changed, but it happens that we bring in 1-3 additional repos per release and work with them.

We release a new version about 5-6 times a year. Although we have a lot of code split up into many repos the product is basically a monolith (Java uberjar).

Right now we are using Bitbucket where we use something they call "Projects" to organize a bunch of repositories together. One project represents a release for us, and we create a new project for each release. At any time we at least have two active projects: The project in prod that we keep alive in case of hot-fixes as well as the project that is the upcoming release that is actively worked with.

We are looking to switch to Github and Github Actions for our build tool and are unsure of how to go about this. Github doesn't seem to have the equivalent of projects so we will have to use branches to accomplish this. We looked at Git Flow and it seems to suit us pretty well, but I'm confused about how it would work when you have so many repositories. Questions like how to keep branches synced between repos and getting Github Actions to work.

Does anyone have any tips on how to get started with this? Is there some things we should keep in mind?

Thanks.

Comment: see [Where to start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)

Comment: Why do you have so many repositories? If you have to coordinate things between them then it seems like they're not really independent and you'd be better served by merging them together into a much smaller number of git repos - ideally just one.

Comment: GitFlow is a branching and merging strategy for a single repository, and not a strategy for organising multiple repositories, nor is it a release management strategy which appears to be what you're looking for here.  Furthermore, this is not a good use-case for branching either so branching/GitFlow appear to be a red herring here (or perhaps a topic for a different question?).     However technically there is no reason why a GitHub action for one repository couldn't pull down other repositories.

Answer (score 1):

That does sound like an awful lot of repositories, and perhaps some of them should be combined if synchronization is key. With regard to keeping repos synced with one another, perhaps [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) would help.

As far as projects go, [GitHub does have projects](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/planning-and-tracking-with-projects). I'm not sure how they differ from BitBucket projects, but they do allow you to reference several repos within one project.

Your statements about branches and Git Flow indicate that maybe your team hasn't been using branches effectively in the past, so you might want to reconsider your dev process, which it sounds like you're doing already. Please update your question with more details about your process if you want better feedback.

Best of luck, it sounds like a complex system.